# Summing multiple observation rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with 4 observations for 90 variables. The observations are answer to a questionnaire of the type "completely agree" to "completely disagree", expressed in percentages. I want to sum the two positive observations (completely and somewhat agree) and the two negative ones (completely and somewhat disagree) for all variables. Is there a way to do this in R?

My dataset looks like this:

```
   Albania  Andorra  Azerbaijan  etc.
1  13.3     18.0     14.9        ...
2  56.3     45.3     27.2        ...
3  21.3     27.2     28.0        ...
4  8.9      9.4      5.2         ...
```

And I want to sum rows 1+2 and 3+4 to look something like this:

```
   Albania  Andorra  Azerbaijan  etc.
1  69.6     63.3     65.4        ...
2  30.2     36.6     33.2        ...
```

I am really new to R so I have no idea how to go about this. All answers to similar questions I found on this website and others either have character type observations, multiple rows for the same observation (with missing data), or combine all the rows into just 1 row. My problem falls in none of these categories, I just want to collapse some of the observations.

Comment: Your problem falls in many existing categories. Where is your grouping variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have four rows, it's probably easiest to just add the first two rows together and the second two rows together. You can use `rbind` to stick the two resulting rows together into the desired data frame:

```r
rbind(df[1,] + df[2, ], df[3,] + df[4,])
#>   Albania Andorra Azerbaijan
#> 1    69.6    63.3       42.1
#> 3    30.2    36.6       33.2
```

---

**Data taken from question**

```r
df <- structure(list(Albania = c(13.3, 56.3, 21.3, 8.9), Andorra = c(18, 
45.3, 27.2, 9.4), Azerbaijan = c(14.9, 27.2, 28, 5.2)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be by summing every 2 rows with `rowsum` and using `gl` with `k = 2` like in the following coding:

```r
rowsum(df, gl(n = nrow(df), k = 2, length = nrow(df)))
#>   Albania Andorra Azerbaijan
#> 1    69.6    63.3       42.1
#> 2    30.2    36.6       33.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
   group_by(grp = gl(n(), 2, n())) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), sum))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  grp   Albania Andorra Azerbaijan
  <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 1        69.6    63.3       42.1
2 2        30.2    36.6       33.2
```